# my API is not working idk why , help is appreciated

Tags: reactjs, rest, project

1. my form code

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function ({ movieName }) {
  const [movie, setMovie] = useState("");
  const changeHandle = (e) => {
    setMovie((m) => e.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandle = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    movieName(movie);
    setMovie("");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandle}>
      <label htmlFor="movie">movie name </label>
      <input type="text" value={movie} onChange={changeHandle} />
      <button> Submit </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

2)my searchbar code

```
import MovieForm from "./MovieForm";
import react from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";


export default function MovieSearchBar() {
  const [formData, setData] = useState("");
  const [responseData, setResponse] = useState({ Data: null, loading: true });

  console.log(formData);
  console.log(responseData);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const options = {
          method: "GET",
          url: "https://movies-api14.p.rapidapi.com/search",
          params: {
            query: formData,
          },
          headers: {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key":
              "bb39fbd85emshe8dd5bbe01a959fp1483dfjsn281f51c9d2c9",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "movies-api14.p.rapidapi.com",
          },
        };

        const response = await axios.request(options);
        const searchResult = response.data;
        console.log(searchResult);

        setResponse({ data: searchResult, loading: false });
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    };
  }, [formData]);

  const movieName = (m) => {
    setResponse({ data: null, loading: true });
    setData(m);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {responseData.loading && <h1> It's loading... </h1>}

      <MovieForm movieName={movieName} />
      <h1>{responseData.title}</h1>
      <p>{responseData.genre ? responseData.genre.join(",") : null}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've been building a movies searchbar but something is off and isn't working ,

I am speculating it's something related to my API cuz my code seems ok.

I tried using console.log to troubleshoot what i noticed api maybe is to blame althpugh ive tried it from the site and it seemed to work multiple actually do not work so idk

Answer (score 0):

You've defined a function inside your `useEffect` but haven't called it. Call your function to trigger its execution:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      const options = {
          method: "GET",
          url: "https://movies-api14.p.rapidapi.com/search",
          params: {
            query: formData,
          },
          headers: {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key":
              "bb39fbd85emshe8dd5bbe01a959fp1483dfjsn281f51c9d2c9",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "movies-api14.p.rapidapi.com",
          },
      };

      const response = await axios.request(options);
      const searchResult = response.data;
      console.log(searchResult);

      setResponse({ data: searchResult, loading: false });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  fetchData(); // Call the fetchData function
}, [formData]);
```

Comment: Thanks you were right, didn't know I had to do this

Comment: Glad I could help